# Laravel 8: InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [admin] is not defined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to build a multiple authentication system with Laravel Jetstream (Users & Admins). Normal user login is working as it should, however the admin login is showing me this error.

[image: InvalidArguementException (Screenshot)]

I did some research and tried clearing cache by running couple of commands,

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

But it didn't solved the problem.

Here's my config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

AdminStatefulGuard.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Guards;

interface AdminStatefulGuard extends Guard
{
    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return bool
     */
    public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false);

    /**
     * Log a user into the application without sessions or cookies.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function once(array $credentials = []);

    /**
     * Log a user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function login(Authenticatable $user, $remember = false);

    /**
     * Log the given user ID into the application.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|bool
     */
    public function loginUsingId($id, $remember = false);

    /**
     * Log the given user ID into the application without sessions or cookies.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|bool
     */
    public function onceUsingId($id);

    /**
     * Determine if the user was authenticated via "remember me" cookie.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function viaRemember();

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function logout();
}
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline;
use App\Actions\Fortify\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession;
use App\Actions\Fortify\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The guard implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected $guard;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard  $guard
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard)
    {
        $this->guard = $guard;
    }

    public function loginForm(){

        return view('auth.login', ['guard' => 'admin']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the login view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse
     */
    public function create(Request $request): LoginViewResponse
    {
        return app(LoginViewResponse::class);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate a new session.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->loginPipeline($request)->then(function ($request) {
            return app(LoginResponse::class);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the authentication pipeline instance.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
     */
    protected function loginPipeline(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback) {
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                call_user_func(Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback, $request)
            ));
        }

        if (is_array(config('fortify.pipelines.login'))) {
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                config('fortify.pipelines.login')
            ));
        }

        return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter([
            config('fortify.limiters.login') ? null : EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled::class,
            Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication()) ? RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class : null,
            AttemptToAuthenticate::class,
            PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
        ]));
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request): LogoutResponse
    {
        $this->guard->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return app(LogoutResponse::class);
    }
}
```

FortifyServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use App\Actions\Fortify\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use App\Actions\Fortify\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use Auth;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->when([AdminController::class, AttemptToAuthenticate::class, RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class])
            ->needs(StatefulGuard::class)
            ->give(function(){
                return Auth::guard('admin');
            });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
    }
}
```

Admin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

Comment: php artisan cache: clear

Comment: Where is your `admin` guard?

Comment: @GabrieleMartini tried it, still the same error.

Comment: @JuanEizmendi updated the question, please review

Comment: Did you register with the service provider?

Comment: @JuanEizmendi Yep I did!

Comment: [Check here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards) `Auth:extend('admin', ...` so it knows it's call admin

Comment: please show your Admin model

Comment: It's a bit weird, maybe try renaming the guard

Comment: I fixed it! I had made a silly mistake in routes middleware part. Thank you all for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

If someone still needs an answer to this.

Check your `routes/web.php`

Look for `Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum,admin', 'verified'])`

Make sure to remove the space before `admin`, if any.

That should be it.